# Subquery with title in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have 2 template:

```
- Relations
     - name1
     - name2

and

- People
     - mainlabel ( the name of the guy as title of my page ) 
     - age
     - etc..
```

Ok, now I would find every people friend of "MrX", and retrieve his personal information ( like age etc.. )

The query doesn't work, but i think it explains the concept:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:People]]  [[**NAME OF PRESENT GUY**::<q>[[name1::{{SUBJECTPAGENAME}}]]</q>]]
|?
|?age
|?eyes
}}
```

where SUBJECTPAGENAME="MrX"

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your property is called `Is a friend of`:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:People]]  [[Is a friend of::MrX]]
 |?age
 |?eyes
}}
```

The syntax is always `Property::Value`. I don't know what you mean by “SUBJECTPAGENAME”, but you can use the name of the current page like this

Assuming that your property is called `Is a friend of`:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:People]]  [[Is a friend of::{{PAGENAME}}]]
 |?age
 |?eyes
}}
```